# CMake syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

Is there any Addin that brings syntax highlighting for CMakeList.txt files to Visual Studio 2015?

BTW: For Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2013 there is [CMake Tools for Visual Studio](https://cmaketools.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the codeplex site again. Released just over a week ago, a build with Visual Studio 2015 and Cmake 3.4 support: [CMake Tools for Visual Studio 1.4](http://cmaketools.codeplex.com/releases/view/619984)

Comment: It looks dead. How can you install it?

Comment: You may need to refer to a more recent thread like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741850/creating-a-cmake-project-with-visual-studio as, yes, CMake Tools for Visual Studio 1.4 is dead.