# cmake project not seen in visual studio 2017

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I download the visual studio 2017  but Cmake Executable Template is not show when I created new project.
[Downloading time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q08GF.png)
CMake project not seen in visual studio 2017'
[Cmake is not seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPrdr.png)

Comment: It seems you have already ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795184/cmake-file-not-seen-in-visual-studio-2017) about the same problem. Instead of creating new question, [edit] the previous one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake file not seen in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795184/cmake-file-not-seen-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a cmake project with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741850/creating-a-cmake-project-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how [CMake support in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/) works.

Visual Studio does not provide a "New Project" wizard for CMake. Instead, you manually create a folder with a (potentially empty) `CMakeLists.txt` file, which you can then load into Visual Studio via

*File->Open->CMake...*

[image: Open CMake option in File menu]

Once opened, you can edit your `CMakeLists.txt` from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Just a hint: To make it easier to start with a CMake project in VS2017 I've written an VS extension to add "CMake Project Wizards". See [Creating a cmake project with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741850/creating-a-cmake-project-with-visual-studio/47061073#47061073) or directly at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oOFlorianOo.CMakeProjectWizards

Comment: ok i am opening cmake worongly . thanks problem solved