# CMake Compiling Error

Tags: compilation, cmake

I'm trying to compile Aseprite's source code using CMake and Ninja, but when I compile I get an error...

Here's the error log:

> BlockquoteCompiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -c
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -c
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -Aa
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -c
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: --c++
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: --ec++
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: -c
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: --c++
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
>   Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags: --ec++
>
> The output was:
>   The system cannot find the file specified

How can I fix it?

~Stefano

Comment: Do you have C and C++ compilers installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CMake, and I also have Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Hm, I am unsure whether Ninja will work with `cl` compiler, provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variable used by CMake to detect Visual C++ compiler tools for Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069632/environment-variable-used-by-cmake-to-detect-visual-c-compiler-tools-for-ninja). It looks like you're picking up a GCC toolchain installed somewhere on your PC. You could also check [Creating a cmake project with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741850/creating-a-cmake-project-with-visual-studio); the wizard does include a working `CMakeSettings.json` example utilizing Ninja.

Comment: And make sure to have the latest VS 2017 version. The `ninja` support was improved a lot over the last releases (`cl.exe` is now the default).

Comment: I tried also to use toolchains but not working.